# How to use rand -- C99 version

Tags: c, for-loop, random, c99

I am writing a ***C*** program and i want to use `for` like this :

```
for(int i=0 ; i < something ; i++ )
```

so I need to use ***C99*** version in order to ***initialize*** the ***counter*** of for inside the " ( ) " but ***C99*** version doesn't work with `rand()` function .

In fact on the man page of `rand()` mentions : " that the function is not part of C99 but part of POSIX "

Any ideas in order to avoid initializing the counter before `for` ..

***//UPDATE***

The output of ***compile*** is :

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rand_r’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Code :

```
array[i] = rand_r(&seed) % MAX + MIN;
```

- >  array[i] type is char* (i have already dynamically allocated space for it)

Thanks

Comment: `rand` should work just fine. Did you `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Comment: Also, [it's right there in the C99 standard, section 7.20.2.1.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Comment: Update your question to show clearly *how* it doesn't work. Show us the code that falls to compile and the error message.

Comment: I want to declare the counter inside every `for-loop `because I am using many for-loops inside my program and I don't want to have many different variables every time !

Comment: I have updated my first post with example + code !

Comment: *In fact on the man page of `rand()` mentions : " that the function is not part of C99 but part of POSIX "* -- I don't believe that.

Comment: You're calling `rand_r`. Why are you asking about `rand`? And neither `rand` nor `rand_r` has anything to do with C99-style `for` loops.

Comment: Yes, there's a big difference between `rand` and `rand_r`.

Comment: Sorry I am new into programming aren't they the same function but `rand_r` is thread-safe ?

Comment: User1911, modifying your question in a way that totally invalidates all comments and answers is not a good idea. You should, if the question is fundamentally different (and it is if you're talking about a totally different function), just ask a new question. This one will then probably be closed and deleted as not enough info. I've rolled it back to the latest version that makes sense.

Comment: If I knew the answer I wouldn't ask here.. my question is how to use them, both `rand_r` or `rand` with `for-loop` initializing the counter inside `( )` . What I know is that I need to use C99 version when compiling to solve the problem with for-loop but i thought that was causing problem to `rand_r` no? correct me if I am wrong please or if that's not the problem at all..

Comment: I didn't change the question i just updated it with `rand_r` instead of `rand`..

Comment: User1911, see the last paty of my answer. If you want C99 but with GNU extensions like rand_r, compile with `-std=gnu99` rather than `-std=c99`. And the change from `rand` to `rand_r` _does_  actually invalidate all answers/comments which are basically stating you can do what you propose.

Comment: That solved my problem..!! the `-std=gnu99` thing.  Thanks a lot and sorry for any inconvenience I might have caused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rand()` is very *much* part of the C99 standard, you just have to make sure you include the correct header file.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    return rand() % 10;
}
```

The `stdlib.h` header file is covered in `7.20` of the C99 standard, and `rand()` is covered in `7.20.2`.

---

If your man page is stating it's not part of C99, then it's incorrect. Mine (under Debian Jessie) clearly states:

> The functions rand() and srand() conform to SVr4, 4.3BSD, C89, ***C99***, POSIX.1-2001.

But, of course, it's the standard itself which is the controlling document.

---

You *may* be misreading the man page, or whoever wrote the man page may be confused. The `random()` and `srandom()` functions are not part of C99 (they're POSIX), but `rand()` and `srand()` *definitely* are.

Or you may be using `rand_r`, the re-entrant version. That too is POSIX but not C99.

If you want to use `gcc` in C99 mode to get the `for (int i = 0...` functionality, but *still* want to be able to call non-C99 functions, compile with `-std=gnu99` rather than `-std=c99`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out ! you are right i was reading about random() and srandom() :/

Comment: That solved my problem.. the `-std=gnu99` Thanks a lot and sorry for any inconvenience I might have caused

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you've misunderstood several things.

`rand()`, `rand_r()`, and `random()` are three distinct functions.

`rand()` is specified by the ISO C standard, and is declared in `<stdlib.h>`. It's included in all editions of the C standard (1990, 1999, and 2011). That means that you can depend on *any* conforming hosted C implementation to provide it (by definition; any hosted implementation that doesn't implement `rand()` is non-conforming). (Conforming freestanding implementations are not required to provide `rand()`, or any library functions at all; such implementations are generally for embedded systems.)

`rand_r()` is not specified by the ISO C standard; instead, it's specified by the POSIX standard. POSIX defines a number of library functions on top of what ISO C defines. The fact that C99 doesn't specify `rand_r()` does *not* mean that you can't use `rand_r()` in a C99 program; it merely means that you can't use it in a *portable* C99 program. (A 100% portable C program cannot depend on POSIX, since not all implementations support POSIX.) `rand_r()`, like `rand()`, is declared (if it's declared at all) in `<stdlib.h>`. You may need to do something extra to enable `rand_r()` and other POSIX-specific functions. For gcc, you can do so by *not* specifying `-pedantic`, or by specifying `-std=gnu99` (C99 with GNU extensions), or by adding

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1
```

to the top of your source file, *before* the `#include <stdlib.h>`.

`rand_r()` is similar to `rand()`, but it's designed to be thread-safe because it uses a seed controlled by the caller rather than an implicit statically allocated seed.

Note that the POSIX standard says that `rand_r()` may be removed from a future POSIX standard, probably because there are much better pseudo-random number generators.

`random()` is yet another distinct function. It's like `rand()`, but somewhat more sophisticated. Like `rand_r()`, `random()` is defined by POSIX but not by ISO C. Similar considerations apply if you want to use `random()`. For reasons that are not entirely clear to me, you need to use different symbol (`_SVID_SOURCE` rather than `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`). As for any function, you should read the documentation to find out exactly how to use it.

None of this has anything to do with C99-style `for` loops. C90 does not permit loops of the form:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i ++) { /* ... */ }
```

That feature was added to the language by the 1999 standard (and of cource retained in the 2011 standard). This is core feature of the language, unrelated to the standard library.

To use C99-style `for` loops, you need to use a compiler that accepts them, possibly with a command-line option to tell it to use the 1999 standard or later.

To use a POSIX-specific function (or *any* library function), you need to read the documentation for the particular function and do what it says, which includes `#include`ing the header that defines it, possibly defining some symbol to enable it, and possibly adding extra command-line options when invoking the compiler or linker.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stdlib` library and add following code .

```
#include <stdlib.h>
var_name =( rand() % 50);
```